# multiple jQuery tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have a working example of my tabs using jQuery

http://jsfiddle.net/barrycorrigan/gs8mp9kz/

Using the following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    });
});
```

my problem is I need to be able to have multiple tabs on the same page. So I tried doing this. I tried just changing the class names but it still doesn't work 100% plus the code isn't well written.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul.tabs-fixtures li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.tabs-fixtures li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    });

    $('ul.tabs-media li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.tabs-media li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    });

});
```

Can anyone help me write this better and get it working for multiple tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a container element

```
<div class="tab-ct">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="next-game">Tab 1</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="table">Tab 2</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="last-game">Tab 3</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="next-game" class="tab-content current">
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </div>
    <div id="table" class="tab-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div id="last-game" class="tab-content">
        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
</div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab'), $ct = $(this).closest('.tab-ct');

        $ct.find('ul.tabs li.current').removeClass('current');
        $ct.find('.tab-content.current').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qubdnx8f/)